# Scrapy - adding an unique ID to scraped data

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a list of products every day using Scrapy but the products do not have unique ID numbers. So I have tried to manually assign 1,2,3,4 in the CSV file but this is not working since the products are changing from 1 to 5 for example if the site changes. Do you have any other solution that you can think so when I upload to my database the products will not duplicate?
Also, is there a way to ask Scrapy to automatically add 1,2,3,4 automatically?
Cheers.

Comment: No one? Please I really need help :(

Comment: What about having the product URL as the unique ID?

Comment: I thought about this I am going to check if this works. :)

Comment: @Umair what if I need to change some text in the output CSV file do you know how can I do that? For example I have scraped "ADD TO CART" from site but want this to be "IN STOCK" in the output CSV. Is there a way to do that? Cheers

Comment: Do it in your python code, like `if "ADD TO CART" in some_variable:` then do `item['is_stock'] = "in stock"`

Comment: @Umair it did not work :(  May I ask your help on where exactly to add this line and if there is any space or coma missing? Cheers

Comment: Could you please post your code? Otherwise i cant help

Comment: @Umair oh gosh sorry, here it goes (in another topic I have posted earlier): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731142/portia-scrapy-how-to-replace-or-add-values-to-output-json

Comment: Where is `parse_item` method?

Comment: @Umair I am not sure I got your question. Are you looking for any other file specifically?

Comment: I did answer your question on your other question, please check

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49735993/4094231

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Scrapinghub Cloud, you can call the API to get the latest job ID when running, and the ID will be unique for the job.